# k8s client-go rest.Config api.Config

Tags: client-go

I am trying to run a tool(Tekton cli) in a container.

It could be any tool using kubeconfig, as long I can give it a parameter of kubeconfig.

In code I can use `InClusterConfig`, but I am using a tool that do not use `InClusterConfig`, so I was thinking maybe I can write out the kubeconfig file from client-go `InClusterConfig` and use it as a parameter to the tool(Tekton cli)

I found some usage of [clientcmd.WriteToFile](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/228dada99554f2e0f7ef07e24f2a4a88c0e448bb/tools/clientcmd/config.go) but I can not figure out how to convert rest.Config to api.Config - and why are there so many Config types.

Anyways do you know how to write out `restclient.InClusterConfig` to a file, so it can be used as kubeconfig file?

```
if clusterConfig, err := restclient.InClusterConfig(); err == nil {
    if tempFile, err := ioutil.TempFile(os.TempDir(), "kubeconfig-"); err == nil {
        // problem >> kubeConfig := createKubeConfig(clusterConfig)
        clientcmd.WriteToFile(*kubeConfig, tempFile.Name())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ClientConfig` may be instantiated based on a `KubeConfig`. The `ClientConfig` has a method `ClientConfig()` which returns `*rest.Config`; it also has a method `RawConfig()` which may be used to get an `api.Config`.

The `KubeConfig` may then be written back to a file using the `clientCmd.WriteToFile()` method and passing the `api.Config` returned from `RawConfig()`.

```go
package main

import (
   "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
   "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
   "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd/api"
   "log"
)   

var clientCfg clientcmd.ClientConfig

clientCfg, err = clientcmd.NewClientConfigFromBytes(kubeConfig)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}

var restCfg *rest.Config

restCfg, err = clientCfg.ClientConfig()
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}

var apiCfg api.Config

apiCfg, err = clientCfg.RawConfig()
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}

err = clientcmd.WriteToFile(apiCfg, filename)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
```